# How to specify a variable to contain a list for powershell in Gitlab CI?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci.yml

I need to set a variable in a Gitlab CI file to contain a list of filepaths that would work in powershell. For example:

```yaml
build:
  tags:
  - windows
  variables:
    PROCESS_FILES: output/file1.txt output/file2.txt output/file3.txt
   script:
     - |
       foreach($f in $PROCESS_FILES)
       {
         Write-Output "$f"
       }
```

Has the output of:

```
output/file1.txt output/file2.txt output/file3.txt
```

I want the output to be:

```
output/file1.txt
output/file2.txt
output/file3.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define the Gitlab CI variable `PROCESS_FILES` as a string and it holds files delimited by a comma.

```
PROCESS_FILES: "output/file1.txt,output/file2.txt,output/file3.txt"
```

Then, use the `-split` operator in PowerShell:

```
   script:
 - |
   $files = $PROCESS_FILES -split ","
   foreach($f in $files)
   {
     Write-Output "$f"
   }
```